# Change "Click to sort by this column" default text using jHtml::_('grid.sort'

Tags: php, joomla

I'm writing a backend component, with columns generated by something like this:

`<th><?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort', 'Column Title', 'table_column', $listDirn, $listOrder) ?></th>`

In the backend, when you hold the mouse over the column header, you get this message: "Click to sort by this column."

We want to use tool tips and a title tag to give deeper explanations on each column instead of that default message.  Came across this page: https://docs.joomla.org/API17:JHtmlJGrid::action

```
public static function action (
    $i
    $task
    $prefix=''
    $text=''
    $active_title=''
    $inactive_title=''
    $tip=false
    $active_class=''
    $inactive_class=''
    $enabled=true
    $translate=true
    $checkbox='cb'
)
```

But have been unsuccessful in getting that tooltip to fire.  Any ideas on overriding that default message?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I investigated a little bit and it seems that `JHtml::_('grid.sort', 'Column Title', 'table_column', $listDirn, $listOrder)` is just triggering `JHtmlGrid::sort` in `libraries/cms/html/grid.php`.

This class in particular allow you to "improve" the text in the tooltip.
I said "improve" because the text  "Click to sort by this column." is hardcoded and your custom text will be above that text.

To do that you have to use the following code:

```php
JHtml::_('grid.sort', 'Column Title', 'table_column', $listDirn, $listOrder, null, 'asc', '<h1>Here my custom code</h1> wow even <b>html</b>!');
```

*Ok but I want to remove "Click to sort by this column." , how can I do it ?*

Create a new file in your component called MySort.php for eg.
In there require `libraries/cms/html/grid.php` and create new class MySort that extend JHtmlGrid.

In there just copy the method sort from `JHtmlGrid` and remove this constant `JGLOBAL_CLICK_TO_SORT_THIS_COLUMN`.

Ok now you are able to use `MySort::sort('Column Title', 'table_column', $listDirn, $listOrder, null, 'asc', '<h1>Here my custom code</h1> wow even <b>html</b>!')`;

```php
class MyGrid extends JHtmlGrid
{
    public static function sort($title, $order, $direction = 'asc', $selected = '', $task = null, $new_direction = 'asc', $tip = '')
    {
        JHtml::_('behavior.core');
        JHtml::_('bootstrap.tooltip');

        $direction = strtolower($direction);
        $icon = array('arrow-up-3', 'arrow-down-3');
        $index = (int) ($direction == 'desc');

        if ($order != $selected)
        {
            $direction = $new_direction;
        }
        else
        {
            $direction = ($direction == 'desc') ? 'asc' : 'desc';
        }

        $html = '<a href="#" onclick="Joomla.tableOrdering(\'' . $order . '\',\'' . $direction . '\',\'' . $task . '\');return false;"'
            . ' class="hasTooltip" title="' . JHtml::tooltipText(($tip ? $tip : $title)) . '">';

        if (isset($title['0']) && $title['0'] == '<')
        {
            $html .= $title;
        }
        else
        {
            $html .= JText::_($title);
        }

        if ($order == $selected)
        {
            $html .= ' <i class="icon-' . $icon[$index] . '"></i>';
        }

        $html .= '</a>';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

borracciaBlu's answer works if the method is called with

```
MyGrid::sort('Column Title', 'table_column', $listDirn, $listOrder, null, 'asc', '<h1>Here my custom code</h1> wow even <b>html</b>!');
```

instead of

```
MySort::sort('Column Title', 'table_column', $listDirn, $listOrder, null, 'asc', '<h1>Here my custom code</h1> wow even <b>html</b>!');
```